# Question about a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> For a linear transformation $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ can we prove there is a subspace $U$ where $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(U)=n-2$ such that $A(U)\leq U$?

Starting in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we know that the $0$-space has this property but lines through the origin ($1$-spaces) do not necessarily have this property. The same if true for $\mathbb{R}^3$: For any matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we can find some $1$-space such that the image of that $1$ space is either itself or the $0$-space but we cant necessarily find a $2$-space.

Comment: I think this follows from the existence of a "rational canonical form," which you can find discussed in the better Linear Algebra textbooks (and no doubt all over the internet). Have a look around, and report back on what you find!

Comment: A subspace $U$ for which $A(U) \subseteq U$ is called an "$A$-invariant subspace".

Comment: For any $A$ with $n$ is odd, we can necessarily find such a $U$ of *any* dimension (so your statement about $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}$ is incorrect).  If $n$ is even, then either we can only find such subspaces of even dimension, or we can once again find such a $U$ of any desired dimension.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So for the matrix which represents rotation about the x axis followed by a rotation about the z axis, which $2$-space satisfies the property?

Comment: @AbCd That depends on what angle you have rotated by.  If we're talking about a $90^\circ$ counterclockwise rotation about each axis, then the corresponding matrix is
$$
\pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0},
$$
and the plane preserved here is spanned by $(-1,-1,2)$ and $(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3},2)$.  In general, if a real matrix has a complex eigenvalue, then the span of the real an imaginary parts of the corresponding eigenvector is a $2$-dimensional invariant subspace.

Comment: @AbCd If you prefer, any composition of rotations in $\Bbb R^3$ is a rotation.  So, any composition of rotations will preserve the plane perpendicular to the "axis of rotation", i.e. the orthogonal complement of the eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1$.  For my previous comment, the same plane can be described as the orthogonal complement to $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So if $n$ is odd $\chi_A(\lambda)$ has a real root $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and thus a one-dimesional invariant subspace and an $n-1$-dimensional invariant subspace ( the orthogonal complement), and if $n$ is even and $\lambda$ is a complex root of $\chi_A(\lambda)$ then $\overline{\lambda}$ is another complex root, then $v+\overline{v},v-\overline{v}$ span a two dimensional invariant subspace, where $v$ is an eigenvector to $\lambda$.

Comment: Using these two facts and induction it is possible to proof: For $n$ odd there are invariant subspaces of all possible sub-dimensions, for $n$ even there are invariant subspaces of all possible even sub-dimensions. Is that correct?

Comment: @PeterMelech Basically correct.  Keep in mind that some care is required in the case that $A$ is not diagonalizable

Comment: Correction to my third comment: that second vector should have been $(-\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3},0)$.

Answer (score 3):

This follows directly from the existence of real Schur form. In general, if $L:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ is a linear operator, there exists an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$ with respect to which the matrix representation of $L$ is in the form of
$$
\pmatrix{R_1&\ast&\ast&\cdots&\ast\\ &R_2& \ast&\cdots&\ast\\ &&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\ &&&\ddots&\ast\\ &&&&R_k},
$$
where each $R_i$ is either a real $1\times1$ matrix (i.e. a real scalar) or a real multiple of some $2\times2$ rotation matrix. The $R_i$s can also be arranged in a way that the $1\times1$ sub-blocks precede the $2\times2$ sub-blocks on the block diagonal.

In particular, if we take $L:x\mapsto Ax$, then there exists a real orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $QAQ^T$ is in real Schur form. It follows that the first $n-2$ columns of $Q$ form an invariant subspace of $A$.

But surely, the use of real Schur form is an overkill. Since $A^T$ either has at least two real eigenvalues or a non-real spectrum, it can be shown (in the same spirit of the existential proof of real Schur form) that
$$
QA^TQ^T=\pmatrix{M&\ast\\ 0&\ast}
$$
for some real $2\times2$ matrix $M$ that is either upper triangular or a real scalar multiple of a rotation matrix. Then the last $n-2$ columns of $Q$ form an invariant subspace of $A$.